# Sails.js Waterline: User, Role, Task models, Please give me some suggestions on my final model design

Tags: sails.js, waterline

This question might be related to database schema design in sails.js waterline.

One task need to record different roles of users. For example, a `Task` need to know who are `fooUsers` and `barUsers` in this task. What is the best way to handle this? (foo and bar are different roles for a user)

## More Context

- A `User` will have different `Role`s.
- The roles of the user might change in the future.
- A `User` will only be one `Role` in one `Task`.
- The `Role` of a `User` in a specific `Task` will never change.
- A `Task` will have many users involved.
- All tasks are the **SAME** type.
- The total number of Roles will NOT change.

For example:

One task has four users: `UserA` with `Role1`, `UserB` with `Role2`, `UserC` with `Role3`, `UserD` with `Role1`.

In the future, `UserA` might have `Role2` and `Role3`. But that **doesn't** affect what role of the `UserA` is in the above task.

## My Final Design

```js
// User.js
attributes: {
    tasks: {
        collection: 'task',
        via: 'users'
    },
    roles: {
        collection: 'role',
        via: 'users'
    },
    userTaskRoles: {
        collection: 'userTaskRole',
        via: 'user'
    }
}

// Task.js
attributes: {
    users: {
        collection: "user",
        via: "tasks"
    },
    userTaskRoles: {
        collection: 'userTaskRole',
        via: 'task'
    }
}

// Role.js
attributes: {
    users: {
        collection: 'user',
        via: 'roles'
    },
    userTaskRoles: {
        collection: 'userTaskRole',
        via: 'role'
    }
}

// UserTaskRole.js
attributes: {
    task: {
        model: 'task'
    },
    user: {
        model: 'user'
    },
    role: {
        model: 'role'
    }
}
```

I updated this question a lot. The above is my final design. Please give me some feedback whether or not this is good or bad and are there any better design patterns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more context for your use case. Without knowing why you want to do what you want to do, I can provide this answer.

Differentiate foo / bar with a column in your tasks and reference users in a single column like so:

```
// User.js

attributes:{
  tasks: {
    collection: "task",
    via: 'users'
  }
}

// Task.js

attributes: {
  Users: {
    collection: "user",
    via: "tasks"
  },
  type: {
    type: 'string',
    enum: ['foo','bar']
  }
}
```

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. Sorry about last two comments. I just figured out I can even delete comments. I deleted them. I have already updated the question and added/appended more context in the end of my question. Hopefully, you can understand my case this time. Thank you very much for your help and reply.

Comment: I updated my question again and added my two model designs. I am looking forward to your suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your current answer will not work in my case because a task will not be able to distinguish a user is which role (either foo or bar) in this task. All tasks are the **same** type. Please check my *PS1* and *PS2* in the question for more context. Thank you very much for your help.